# Get collection by matching date element and max value of other element of a nested array in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection named "plan" containing nested documents, like this :

```
//1 {
"_id" : ObjectId("55ed97c91ed85902375f60c3"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2015-09-07T13:57:29.700Z"),
"suggestions" : [ 
    {
        "title" : "First suggestion",
        "vote" : 5,
        "_id" : ObjectId("55ed97c91ed85902375f60c5"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-09-07T13:57:29.701Z"),
        "startDate" : ISODate("2015-09-02T13:57:29.701Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2015-09-05T13:57:29.701Z")
    }, 
    {
        "title" : "second suggestion",
        "vote" : 8,
        "_id" : ObjectId("55ed97c91ed85902375f60c4"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-09-07T13:57:29.701Z"),
        "startDate" : ISODate("2015-09-07T13:57:29.701Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2015-09-10T13:57:29.701Z")
    }
],
"__v" : 0
```

},

```
//2 {
"_id" : ObjectId("55f1570fd86512e01f4d55c8"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2015-09-10T10:10:23.381Z"),
"suggestions" : [ 
    {
        "title" : "First suggestion",
        "vote" : 3,
        "startDate" : ISODate("2015-09-10T13:57:29.701Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2015-09-15T13:57:29.701Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("55f1570fd86512e01f4d55ca"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-09-10T10:10:23.381Z")
    }, 
    {
        "title" : "second suggestion",
        "vote" : 2,
        "startDate" : ISODate("2015-09-02T13:57:29.701Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2015-09-04T13:57:29.701Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("55f1570fd86512e01f4d55c9"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-09-10T10:10:23.381Z")
    }
],
"__v" : 0
```

}

And I have to get collection where "suggestions.endDate" less than "ISODate("2015-09-07T13:57:29.701Z")" And "vote" should be greater among all suggestions in a collection. I am expecting only this:

```
       //1 {
"_id" : ObjectId("55ed97c91ed85902375f60c3"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2015-09-07T13:57:29.700Z"),
"suggestions" : [ 
    {
        "title" : "First suggestion",
        "vote" : 5,
        "_id" : ObjectId("55ed97c91ed85902375f60c5"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-09-07T13:57:29.701Z"),
        "startDate" : ISODate("2015-09-02T13:57:29.701Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2015-09-05T13:57:29.701Z")
    }, 
    {
        "title" : "second suggestion",
        "vote" : 8,
        "_id" : ObjectId("55ed97c91ed85902375f60c4"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-09-07T13:57:29.701Z"),
        "startDate" : ISODate("2015-09-07T13:57:29.701Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2015-09-10T13:57:29.701Z")
    }
],
"__v" : 0
```

},

This is the query I am using :

```
        db.plan.aggregate([{$match: {suggestions: {$elemMatch: {endDate: {$lt: ISODate("2015-09-07T13:57:29.701Z")}}}}}, {$sort: {"suggestions.vote": -1}}]).pretty()
```

But that didn't work for me,It is just matching the date. I am new to MongoDb?Any Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, it will work

```
db.plan.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $match: {
                    "suggestions.endDate": {
                        $lt: ISODate("2015-09-10T13:57:29.701Z")
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$sort": {
                    "suggestions.vote": -1
                }
            },
            {
                $limit: 1
            }
        ]
).pretty();
```